# SQL Command for restoring trashed comments

Tags: posts, comments, sql, trash

When trashing a post, also trash related comments
so here is what i want， what‘s’ the sql Command

I want to move some post to trash according their ID， what is the  sql command，I can restore these post and their comments using sql command

Answer (score 2):

I would discourage using raw SQL for moving a post to a trash or back, especially since there's a build in function for it:

```
wp_trash_post( $post_id  );
```

More about the [wp_trash_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trash_post) function.

The opposite is:

```
wp_untrash_post( $post_id  );
```

`wp_untrash_post()` also untrashes trashed comments.

In WP there are functions for many things - for instance you can trash/untrash only comments, leaving the post alone - in that case use: `wp_untrash_post_comments()` and `wp_trash_post_comments()`.

Comment: when i run wp_trash_post($87); it show wrong message in sql command “mysql> wp_trash_post($87);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wp_trash_post($87)' at line 1”

Comment: This is a command that you need to run from within the wordpress files having administrator rights, I didn't know you want to run this scripts in the mysql terminal and that is a different story.

Comment: if want to run this scripts in the mysql terminal ，how?

Comment: But why would you like to do it in the raw SQL? If you analyze the WP source there are many conditions and dependencies to take care of when un/trashing comments/posts in some cases this could be more than a one simple SQL command. If you'd like to do it from the command line but not exactly from MySQL you can check the WP CLI system - command line interface for WP - for instance here is how to [untrash comments](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/comment/untrash/)

Answer (score 0):

Sql Command for trashed a post with comments for that post:

```
$post_status = 'trash';
$post_array = '1, 2, 3'; //post_ids comma separated

$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(                                    
             "UPDATE                          
             `wp_posts`,                                  
             `wp_comments`                                          
              SET                    
              wp_posts.post_status= %s,   
              wp_comments.comment_approved= %s                    
              WHERE                                         
              wp_posts.ID = wp_comments.comment_post_ID AND  
              wp_posts.ID IN ( $post_array )",           
              $post_status,
              $post_status                                 
));
```